# LimeSurvey back browser button issue

Tags: limesurvey

I'm using LimeSurvey 1.92 build 120509, when I press the back button (on the brower) the previous survey page fails to load and instead I get the following broswer error:

```
Document Expired
This document is no longer available.

The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache.As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal browser behavior because  all LimeSurvey pages are created on the fly and so immediately expire.

If you click the 'try again' the previous page will appear. 
However the LimeSurvey makers strongly recommend to use the survey navigation instead of browser navigation.